# Is It Permissible to Use Dinnerware That Has Gold pattern?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I am planning to buy a dinnerware set for my home and I know that we are not allowed to eat in gold instruments. Below is the description for the item that I am planning to buy:

> A sophisticated shade of blue creates a bold border that is
>   embellished with a lush and elegant gold scroll pattern, making a
>   regal statement that will command attention at all your gatherings.

Does this mean this item we cannot buy? But I have also read that we cannot eat only in items that are made of purely gold so we can eat in item that have some gold pattern?

Can anyone clear my confusion?

Comment: if you can understand Arabic Maybe you can get the answer from this https://www.binbaz.org.sa/noor/7664

Comment: can't understand arabic :(

Comment: mmm, I'm sorry @john hope that someone can translate for you, i'm not that good person in English :(

Comment: Are you sure it’s real gold and not just a gold colored pattern?

Comment: That's the [item](http://www.mikasa.com/dinnerware-service-for-4/parchment-cobalt/20-piece-dinnerware-set/5146633.html) I am talking about. I am unsure whether I can eat in gold pattern or not as well?

Comment: Whether the item is purely gold or partially plated with gold, you are still not allowed to eat/drink from it. So you should avoid dinnerware with gold-plated patterns.

Comment: Can you provide more clarity and some reference if possible? I thought we can use dinnerware which has some gold like pattern but it's not gold though.

Answer (score -1):

It is forbidden  to eat and drink from a container made entirely of gold or silver, or if a certain piece of gold or silver is used in it. But if they have decorated it with silver and gold plating. There is nothing wrong with eating and drinking from those dishes and it is unobstructed.